# nvarchar column result with question marks

Tags: c#, sql, character-encoding, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to update the queue item and retrieve it's column text content.

the problem is that special signs such as Hebrew chars resulted in question marks: ????

I can see the text perfectly fine by making direct `SELECT` clause (within the `sql management studio`):

```
Message's column
-------
היי     
hey
```

When i try to retrieve the data it get scrambled :

```
 היי     --->    ??? (Not OK)
 hey     --->    hey (OK)
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyQueue](   
    [Message] [nvarchar](1000) NOT NULL 
    --some additional columns
)
```

This is my Stored procudure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MyDequeue] (
)
as
begin
    with CTE as (
            SELECT TOP (100) *
            FROM MyQueue WITH (xlock,READPAST)
            WHERE Locked = 0
            and HasError=0
            and Success=0)
        UPDATE CTE
        SET Locked = 1, LockTime=getUtcDate()
        OUTPUT INSERTED.*;
end
```

I'm reading this item by these function:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyQueue> Dequeue(int batchSize)
    {
        var cmd = dataManager.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "MyDequeue";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (var reader = dataManager.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
            var ordinals = reader.LoadFields();
            List<MyQueue> items = new List<MyQueue>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                items.Add(new MyQueue()
                {
                    Message = reader.GetString(ordinals["Message"])
                    // some additional properties init
                });
            }
            return items;
        }
    }


    public static Dictionary<string, int> LoadFields(this IDataReader reader)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> loadedColumns = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                loadedColumns.Add(reader.GetName(i), i);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException) { }
        }
        return loadedColumns;
    }
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the `MyQueue` table?  This is the first thing to check.

Comment: the data in the table is perfectly fine, i can see it with the select clause directly

Comment: @ShaharS that is important distinction, you might want to edit the question to mention the data in the database is fine instead of as a comment.

Comment: What is `Filters`? What is `LoadFields`?

Comment: Deleted the `Filters`, implemented the `LoadFields`...
Commented the that the data is fine

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the column encoding is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: Does `dataManager.CreateCommand();` return a SqlCommand type or is that an OleDb or Odbc one?

Comment: @ShaharS, so the `SELECT` shows both good and bad (`???`) characters? That suggests data may have been inserted without a parameterized query and the character literal did not have the national (N) prefix (e.g. 'היי' insead of N'היי').

Comment: @rene the `dataManager.CreateCommand();` return `IDbCommand` type

Comment: @DanGuzman Sorry if i was miss understood, what I meant that if i do a simple select clause within the `sql management studio` i can see the data perfectly fine (good - היי), only when i try to retrieve the data throughout the code it get scrambled (question marks) .

Comment: I'm actually interested in the underlying type that implements that IDbCommand. Where or how do you inspect that the retrieved data is scrambeld? In the debugger? A file? Winforms/wpf/uwp app? Web app?

Comment: @rene i'm not sure, its a web app debugger

Comment: Could it be that your code is fine but that the web app debugger is simply showing it wrong? You could try to write it to a Trace file to be 100% sure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rene i'm affraid that its not the web app debugger, i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved (credit to @dan-guzman):

The data need to be insert with parameterized query and the character literal N prefix.

like: `N 'היי'`.